# Nokogiri and concat()

Tags: ruby, xml, xpath, nokogiri

How can I use concat() in a Nokogiri xpath expression? I've tried:

```
xml.xpath("concat(/root/a/text(), /root/b/text())")
```

But that fails with:

> ArgumentError: node_set must be a Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet

Actually it seems like Nokogiri accepts only xpath expressions that start with "." or "/", so I tried these:

```
xml.xpath(".concat(/root/a/text(), /root/b/text())")
xml.xpath("/concat(/root/a/text(), /root/b/text())")
xml.xpath("/concat('foo', 'bar')")
```

But they all fail with this error:

> Nokogiri::XML::XPath::SyntaxError: Invalid expression: /concat('foo',
>   'bar')

I know Nokogiri is based on libxml2 and as such it only implements XPath 1.0. But concat() is part of XPath 1.0. However, a similar function in XPath 2.0 is string-join() and I gave it a chance:

```
xml.xpath("string-join('foo', 'bar')")
```

Error message:

> RuntimeError: xmlXPathCompOpEval: function string-join not found

See, it's a different error message than the one for concat(). So at least the function concat() is being found. One more hint that it might work somehow is...

```
xml.xpath("concat()")
```

...returns the expected error message:

> Nokogiri::XML::XPath::SyntaxError: Invalid number of arguments:
>   concat()

Any chance to get concat() working with arguments?

P.S.: Basic xpath expressions like `xml.xpath("/root/a/text()")` work fine.

Comment: Can you provide a full example of your problem? The XPath with `concat` works okay for me, I suspect you are using the result somewhere where Nokogiri expects something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An XPath query commonly returns a *node-set*, a collection of nodes from the document. In Nokogiri this is represented by the [`Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet) object.

Nokogiri also allows you to use a `NodeSet` with the `xpath` method. In this case Nokogiri [executes the query individually against each of the nodes in the `NodeSet` in turn, and combines them all into a new `NodeSet` which it returns as the result](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/blob/v1.7.0/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb#L87-L93).

Normally this works as you would expect, with the result being the combination of all the nodes that match the query. However, this doesn’t work when using an XPath query that returns something other than a node-set, as in this case.

After executing the query, Nokogiri tries to add the result (which it expects to be a `NodeSet`) to the newly created `NodeSet`. When the result is actually a string [this fails with the error you are getting](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/blob/v1.7.0/ext/nokogiri/xml_node_set.c#L183-L184).

This has been brought up in a [Nokogiri bug](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/656), and added to their [roadmap](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/blob/v1.7.0/ROADMAP.md#better-syntax-around-nodexpath-and-nodesetxpath), but there is no resolution as yet.

The workaround/solution is to make all your non-node-set returning XPath queries on single nodes rather than node-sets. [`at_xpath`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Searchable#at_xpath-instance_method) will return the first matching node for a query, and that node can be used for further `xpath` calls without this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Seem to work for me

```
body = "<root><a>aaa</a><b>bbb</b></root>"
xml = Nokogiri::XML(body)
xml.xpath("concat(/root/a/text(), /root/b/text())") # => "aaabbb"
```

Given your update, maybe try this?

```
body = "<wrapper><root><a>aaa</a><b>bbb</b></root></wrapper>"
xml = Nokogiri::XML(body) 
xml = xml.xpath("wrapper") # returns a node set
xml.map { |each| each.xpath("concat(./root/a/text(), ./root/b/text())") } # => ["aaabbb"]
```

NB, notice the leading `.` to anchor the query at the current node.